# Trying to make DataAccess function pass back a 2d string array with columns and records for UI class to display

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There's two parts to my question, How to do it, and if it's good style to do.

- `TestDataBaseEntities` is the DBContext item being passed.
- `myQuery` is the query being excecuted and read
- `StatusMessage` is passed out of the function for the UI to report whether the operation was a success or not.
- `Records` is what I need help figuring out. I need to figure out how to pass each record back to the calling method of `ReadMan()`.

I was thinking that a 2d string array being passed back would benefit me, because I'd have the data read by this `DataAccess` class, and ready to display in my `UserInterface` class.  But therein lies the problem.

To declare the `string[,]`, I would need to know the size of the string, or implicitly give it dimensions by doing it like this `Records[,] = new string[,] { { FirstField, SecondField }, { FirstField, SecondField } ... }` and so on, BUT can't, because the first record being read in doesn't give the information needed to tell `Records` how large its second index is supposed to be, `[ , ThisIndex]`, If i had this working, i'd pass the 2d `Records` back for the `UserInterface` class to Display to user.

Why have this Read function? Because I'm supposed to separate EF functions from UI right?

```
public class DataAccess
{
    public bool ReadMan(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, IQueryable myQuery, out string StatusMessage, out string[,] Records)
    {
        string ErrorMessage;
        bool bSuccessful;
        string[] ThisRecord;

        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
            () =>
            {   
                foreach (Man m in myQuery)
                {
                    // was thinking ThisRecord could be temporary storage but doesn't seem to work to my benefit.
                    ThisRecord = new string[] { m.ManID.ToString(), m.Name };

                }
            });
        if (bSuccessful)
            StatusMessage = "Records read successfully";
        else
            StatusMessage = ErrorMessage;


        return bSuccessful;
    }

    public bool TryDataBaseAction(TestDatabaseEntities MyDBEntities, out string ErrorMessage, Action MyDBAction)
    {
        UserInterface MyUI = new UserInterface();
        try
        {
            MyDBAction();
            ErrorMessage = "No Error";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT: FIXED

```
    public bool ReadMan(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, IQueryable myQuery, out string StatusMessage, out string[,] Records)
    {
        string ErrorMessage;
        bool bSuccessful;
        string[,] TheseRecords = null;

        // hands an Action() to TryDataBase, as indicated by lambda expression in 3rd arguement.
        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
        () =>
        {
            List<Man> men = myQuery.OfType<Man>().ToList();
            TheseRecords = new string[men.Count, 2];

            // ERROR BELOW: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group' 
            for (int i = 0; i < men.Count; i++)
            {
                TheseRecords[i, 0] = men[i].ManID.ToString();
                TheseRecords[i, 1] = men[i].Name;
            }
        });

        Records = TheseRecords;

        if (bSuccessful)
            StatusMessage = "Records read successfully";
        else
            StatusMessage = ErrorMessage;


        return bSuccessful;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
() =>
{   
    List<Man> men = myQuery.OfType<Man>().ToList();
    Records = new string[men.Count, 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < men.Count; i++)
    {
        Records[i, 0] = men[i].ManID.ToString();
        Records[i, 1] = men[i].Name;
    }
});
```

The key thing here is to convert `myQuery` into a list so that we can get access to its `Count` property. Once we have that it is then straightforward to create the `Records` array.

Whether doing so is good style or not is more subjective and really depends on how your application is architected. Generally speaking I have the data access layer charged with merely executing queries and retrieving data - it is left to the user interface to take care of the visual representation.

Applying this approach to your specfic case, it may have been easier if the `ReadMan` method took a `List` or some other collection as the `out` parameter rather than the 2-D array. This way, the calling method has an easy time of creating the desired representation (you know how many items you are dealing with), plus you avoid having user interface details creeping into the data access layer.

You may be doing this already, but the other thing to consider is how your current approach deals with very large amounts of data. We are materializing everything retreived by `myQuery`, so if you are wanting to implement some form of paging, it will need to manifest itself in `myQuery`.

Comment: This application is developed by me, not for business so I can modify any part of it I want.  I want to create it as a demo of my understanding of programming concepts to increase my marketability for C#.net jobs.  

Your approach makes sense, although I had assumed that to excecute a query, a `foreach statement was required and not a `for` statement.

I can make modifications.  If i want to post more code related to this suggestion you made, should i Ask a new question?

Comment: I have an error with the code you posted above.  "Cannot use ref or out parameter 'Records' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression"

Comment: I have fixed the error I commented above about, but now have a new error that's been revealed.  I have added the code plus description in the original post at the end.

Comment: I can modify the function so that it passes a 2d string list instead of a 2d string array  But for a 2d list, don't i use `List<List<string>>()`?

Comment: I think that error is a mistake on my part. Do this: `for (int i = 0; i < men.Count; i++)` - iterating over the `List<Man>` was my intention here.

Comment: I see.  When i make that change, i face a problem.  I can't use a ref parameter in a lambda expression as i mentioned above, and if i try to define a temporary `string[,]` inside ReadMan to give to the Lambda Expression for assignments, and come back to Readman to try and assign Records the "TheseRecords" value, it tells me error, use of unassigned value TheseRecords.  Apparently TheseRecords doesn't get passed by reference either...  Is there any way around this?

Comment: That error is because `TheseRecords` may not have an assigned value when you go `Records = TheseRecords;`. The fix for this is to simply turn this line `string[,] TheseRecords;` into `string[,] TheseRecords = null;`

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  Cause maybe there could be nothing for Man.Count, in which case it wouldn't assign anything to `TheseRecords`, and then it would be use of an unassigned variable when it hits `Records = TheseRecords;`